# Compare or Match the two generic List sets using Linq

Tags: c#, linq, .net-4.5

Reference to many links for Lists comparision   [Compare two lists C# linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10815387/compare-two-lists-c-sharp-linq) still I'm really not getting matching between the lists clearly.

```
Let's say I have two lists of strings:

 List1: "apple, orange, mango, bananna, butter fruit"

 List2: "butter fruit, grapes, apple, bananna, orange, mango, jack fruit, pineapple"
```

Here i need to check whether the **List1** items are there in **List2** set or not. If it is there return true otherwise false.

I tried with Except but not getting the expected result true or false between the sets.

```
if(List1.Except(List2).Count == 0)
{
  ....
}
```

Comment: Do you want to get True if All the elements in list1 are in list2, or a list of true/false for each element in list1 ?

Comment: I just need true if the list1 items are prsent in list 2

Comment: You're asking us to diagnose a problem with your code *and you haven't even provided the code that isn't working*.

Comment: @sukumar you are missing parentheses within `Count` should be `Count()`,apart from that there is nothing wrong with your approach

Comment: I shown my effort but still DownVote....Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Except

```
if(list1.Except(list2).Any())
{
   //....
}
```

With All(Bobson's comment: Be warned that .All() will succeed if list1 is empty, but the other two will not):

```
list1.All(str => list2.Contains(str));
```

With Any:

```
list1.Any(str => !list2.Contains(str));
```

Comment: Be warned that `.All()` will succeed if `list1` is empty, but the other two will not.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `All` method:

```
return list1.All(list2.Contains);
```

Comment: +1 And if the lists are really long, you can think to push list2 into an HashSet then call Contains on that...

Comment: @digEmAll Which is exactly what `Except` is going to do for you.